# Custom vertical bar like deployment Tracking in New Relic RPM

Tags: newrelic

We want to add additional vertical bars (like the one for deploys) to the New Relic charts, to mark other points in time that are important for us, besides just the deploys.

I did not find anything like this in the docs, is this possible? Or a maybe just a different color. We have things that affect live operation, which we need to visualize like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now there's not a way to add notes like this to charts. The word 'arbitrary' can sound pejorative, but essentially that's what I'd like to see: the ability to add some arbitrary text to a particular time such that anyone viewing a graph will see this note e.g. "Our TV ad airs"

Right now the only way to offer context like this is to either hack the deployment system the way Walden mentioned, or to create a note and add some explanatory text.

https://newrelic.com/docs/site/public-and-private-notes

Neither are ideal for this need, so I'll let our Product Managers know you (and others) would like to see this feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a deployment marker using the API without having to actually deploy changes to your application. This would be useful for marking key times with a reference. Although you can't make this marker a different color it should work for your purposes.

http://newrelic.github.io/newrelic_api/#label-Deployment+Notifications

If you need more help with this, you can submit a ticket at http://support.newrelic.com

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of that - so I asked if it is possible without using the deploy markers. I don't like feature hijacking :\
I also filed a support ticket, which was closed by referring here